# How should I change my legacy application so that it ALWAYS stores files and data in AppData?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I have an application (12 years old and roughly 800,000 lines of code) that writes to its current local directory whenever it creates any sort of file. I need to change the app so it always writes to AppData.

My current course of action is to do a text search for every instance of the text "Streamwriter", "System.IO", or "File.Create" in the code, change the directory its writing to that so it points to AppData instead of whatever it currently is and then just pray that that covers it all.

Is there a comprehensive list of all classes, methods, and objects that can create files in C# .net 4.5? Or is there a better method to achieve what I'm going for?

Comment: To prevent this problem in the future, I would add the directory path to your `.config` file and read the path from there, appending a file name or what ever is necessary. Then if you ever have to change it again, you can just change it in one place, the `config` file. Also, you should be able to edit these files with a simple text editor and `find and replace all`

Comment: You could get a copy of the c# source (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) for I/O and make you own modified version that always writes to AppData.

Comment: Wrap FileSystem IO in your own object (with an interface) with configuration.  If you need to then store files on Azure instead it wouldn't be that hard to implement your own Azure interface.